# product display image not showing drupal

Tags: views, commerce

I have a question about Drupal Commerce (I'm using Drupal 7). I've added a number of products and created a multi-product display for them. I added a product image (it's common for all these products) to the product display. I also have a view of all product displays with images. But when I click and go to the product price and add to cart form, the product image does not show up. What am I missing??? (I did the same on the localhost before and everything worked fine, but probably I forgot to configure something)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a relationship to your view between the node and the product display.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You should add the product image to the product entity itself, rather than the product display node.